# After compiling all the CSS in file and JS in another, what are the following steps to follow?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress-theming, minify

JS and CSS files are inside them, where? Should I delete the separate CSS and JS files? Should I change my header (delete lines of code)? What should I write to call CSS and JS in header?

Step by step, what would you do after "compressing" CSS and JS files of your theme?

Comment: Yes, you would then use the compiled CSS and JS files instead of the individual ones. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete anything. Just make sure that you only link to the new minified versions in header.php. Just tag out the links to the old uncompressed CSS and js files, like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_minified.css" media="screen" />
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />
-->
```

Comment: how call the file js and css ?